# Как сделать эффект чтобы было понятно ,что скриншот сделан

Tags: java, android

У меня есть кнопка которая делает скриншот .  Как сделать какой-то эффект, чтобы было понятно ,что скриншот  сделан.
(чтобы Activity как-то изменилась) и чтобы после этого изменения всё возвращалось на место.

Comment: можно сделать всплывающее сообщение например, чтобы не трогать всю активность

Comment: toast.show("Скриншот сделан")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть для меня лично два решения вашей проблемы:

1. Как сказал я и @Эникейщик, можно сделать всплывающее сообщение toast:

   `Toast.makeText(this, "some text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`
2. Этот вариант более интересный - сделать всплывающее диалоговое окно с отображением скриншота, которое например через 5 секунд висения на экране будет пропадать. Вам в этот диалоговом окне нужно будет разместить imageview и там отображать скриншот.

Надеюсь один из предложенных вариантов поможет в решении вашей проблемы. Удачи :)

Comment: Второй вариант интересней как РЕАЛИЗОВАТЬ?

Comment: я думаю есть смысл задать новый вопрос)) если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галку сбоку :)